# Can an imprinted spell be kicked when it is cast?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can an imprinted spell be kicked when it is cast ?

For example : [Isochron Scepter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Isochron%20Scepter) and [Orim's Chant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=26852)

Can I pay the kicker cost each time I activate Isochron Scepter?

Comment: So you can cast the copy once per the opponent's turn?!  That is nuts!  How would an opponent defend against that if they can't play any spells or attack?

Comment: Presumably, play cards on _your_ turn to cancel it?

Comment: Or cast spells in response and/or before it is activated

Comment: @Jefromi Yes, I understand - I was responding to the comment above (dmikester's).  And from the point of view switched - "They" are the ones "you" are playing it on, so "they" would play on "your" turn to cancel it.

Comment: @Joe Ah, never mind, I thought dimkester had switched point of view for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hideaway Lands and Additional Costs](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/31532/hideaway-lands-and-additional-costs). I know that this is the older question, but the newer question uses better terminology: Does casting a spell for free prevent a player from paying additional costs? For that reason, I am closing this one as a duplicate of the newer one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can pay for Kicker when you can a spell off of the Scepter. The Scepter gives your spell an Alternative Cost, and Kicker is an Additional Cost. These work together to make the full cost of the spell. So you pay {2} to activate the Scepter and then when you cast the Chant you can pay an additional {W} if you want to kick it.

> **117.9.** Some spells have alternative costs. An alternative cost is a cost listed in a spell’s text, or applied to it from another effect, that its controller may pay rather than paying the spell’s mana cost. Alternative costs are usually phrased, “You may [action] rather than pay [this object’s] mana cost,” or **“You may cast [this object] without paying its mana cost.”**
>
> **117.9d** If an alternative cost is being paid to cast a spell, any **additional costs**, cost increases, and cost reductions **that affect that spell are applied to that alternative cost.** (See rule 601.2f.)
>
> **702.32a** Kicker is a static ability that functions while the spell with kicker is on the stack. “Kicker [cost]” means “You may pay an **additional [cost]** as you cast this spell.”

Also from the rulings on [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=292752):

> You don't pay the spell's mana cost. If the spell has X in its mana cost, X is 0. You do pay any additional costs for that spell. You can't use any alternative costs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. When casting a spell w/o paying it's mana cost, you are allowed/required to pay any additional costs. The only cost you ignore is the one printed in the top right.

> **117.8**. Some spells and abilities have additional costs. An additional cost is a cost listed in a spell’s rules text, or applied to a spell or ability from another effect, that its controller must pay at the same time that player pays the spell’s mana cost or the ability’s activation cost. A cost is an additional cost only if it’s phrased using the word “additional.” Note that some additional costs are listed in keywords; see rule 702